# ¿Como puedo conectar una base de sqlite3 desde una carpeta diferente del archivo principal?

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Bueno como lo describe la pregunta quiero organizar mejor los archivos, Pero siempre que me quiero conectar a la base cuando está en otra carpeta Me dice que no la a encontrado, Y no tengo mucha idea de que puedo hacer.
Es en Python y la base de datos es en sqlite3
dejo ejemplo de una parte del código donde la uso
Acá de dejo una imagen del como tengo las carpetas organizadas [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gseRH.png

```
    elif arg=="economia": 
    Conexion = sqlite3.connect("Economia")
    Mi_Cursor = Conexion.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Economia ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
    Mi_Cursor.execute(sql)
    row = Mi_Cursor.fetchone()
    await ctx.send(f'Aquí tienes un dato aleatorio: {row[1]}')
```

Comment: que es lo que está en otra carpeta? la base de datos o el archivo py? agrega una imagen del árbol de archivos si puedes, he hecho una prueba y si mi ddbb está en una carpeta dentro del directorio donde esta el archivo py me la toma sin problemas, siempre que ponga la ruta correcta en sqlite3.conect

Comment: Listo ya puse la imagen, Aunque tenga ya una solución es muy engorrosa lo que quiero es generar esa conexión sin moverme de carpetas, No se si sea posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste usando el modulo OS de Python?

```
import sqlite3
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dbpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(abspath), 'base_de_datos', 'northwind.db')
""""
os.path.abspath devuelve la ruta absoluta del archivo actual
os.path.dirname devuelve el componente directorio de una ruta (la ruta sin el archivo final si es que lo hubiese)
os.path.join concatena direcciones, me quedo la siguiente ruta 
c:\Users\Unnamed\Desktop\jorge\programacion WEB full stack\prueba\Py\base_de_datos\northwind.db
"""
Conexion = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
Mi_Cursor = Conexion.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID > 5"
Mi_Cursor.execute(sql)
row = Mi_Cursor.fetchone()

print(row)
print(dbpath)
```

Este script se encuentra en el directorio raiz, una carpeta llamada 'Py'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo probare, aunque pensé que con las funcionalidades que me ofrece el módulo de sqlite3 podría hacerlo, Muchas gracias Lo probare y te diré si me funciono

Comment: @sebastiandev sqlite3 proporciona una interfaz para trabajar con bases de datos SQLite, y no tiene la responsabilidad de administrar rutas o directorios. Eso es responsabilidad del programador, y el modulo OS facilita ese trabajo.

Comment: Ya lo probe y funcionan tambien de maravilla, Gracias

Comment: @sebastiandev puedes dar upvote para marcar una respuesta como util, y el simbolo de ✓ para aceptarla como la mejor, saludos

Answer (score 1):

En base a la imagen que enviaste hice la misma estructura y lo hice funcionar así:

```
elif arg=="economia": 
    Conexion = sqlite3.connect("Base_Datos/Economia.db")
    Mi_Cursor = Conexion.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Economia ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
    Mi_Cursor.execute(sql)
    row = Mi_Cursor.fetchone()
    await ctx.send(f'Aquí tienes un dato aleatorio: {row[1]}')
```

Más que nada debes indicar la **ruta relativa** de la Base de datos en relación a la ubicación del archivo, en este caso esta dentro de la carpeta **Base_Datos** así que se indica de esa forma.

Para **ruta absoluta** lo puedes añadir cambiando la linea de conexión y añadiendo el import necesario, así:

```
import os
#import necesario al principio del archivo

ruta_base_datos = os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\mi usuario\\test-python\\Base_Datos\\Economia.db")
Conexion = sqlite3.connect(ruta_base_datos)
```

Comment: Probe con las dos opciones que me diste y funcionaron de maravilla, Gracias lo tendré en cuenta para futuros proyectos